# angular ng2-chart :want to display the value as well as one percentage value, which will come from other source but with the same index

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am using angular dough nut chart from ng2-chart.

I am doing customization for tooltip. In my case, apart from the tooltip label and value, there is one another value and that is percentage. On the doughnut chart, I am displaying the value but on-hover, I want to display the value as well as one percentage value, which will come from other source but with the same index.

In order to get the custom percentage value, I just want to call a function(**this.someFunction**) but am not able to do so.

Can it be possible? Please  help.

```
public doughnutChartOptions: any = {
    cutoutPercentage: 55,
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      // Disable the on-canvas tooltip
      enabled: true,
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var tooltipLabel = data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];

          if (tooltipLabel !== null) {
            return tooltipLabel.toUpperCase();
          } else {
            return '';
          }
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
          var tooltipLabel = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
          var total_attritions: number = 0;
          // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
          for (let i in allData) {
            total_attritions = total_attritions + Number(allData[i]);
          }    

          /*let tooltipPercentage = (
            (Number(tooltipData) / total_attritions) *
            100
          ).toFixed(2);*/

          let tooltipPercentage = this.someFunction(tooltipItem.index); // Is it possible, because every time, I am getting undefined

          return [
            ' Attrition Count : ' + tooltipData,
            ' Attrition Percentage : ' + tooltipPercentage + '%',
            ' Total Attritions : ' + total_attritions
          ];
        }
      },
      titleFontSize: 18
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      fullWidth: false,
      labels: {
        padding: 15,
        fontSize: 13,
        usePointStyle: true,
        fontColor: 'rgb(143, 142, 142)',
        boxWidth: 10
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 19
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

// This is the function, which will return the custom value, which will get shown in the tooltip hover.

```
   public someFunction(index) {
        return this.attritionCount[index];
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing to this.someFunction inside wrong scope. Try to change

```
label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
```

to arrow function, it doesn't change the scope

```
label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
```